# Frame only appears some of the time java

Tags: java, user-interface

For some reason (seemingly completely independent of code) the frame of my program will only appear some (maybe 20%) of the time. If I just continuously hit run I evently get the frame to show successfully, but it is never repeatable. has this ever happened to anyone else? I highly doubt this has to do with code but just in case

```
public class Trader{

public static Trader INSTANCE = new Trader();
JTextArea msgBox;
ApiController m_controller;

Connection connect;
Quotes quotes;

ArrayList<String> m_acctList = new ArrayList();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    INSTANCE.run();
}


public  void run(){
    connect = new Connection();
}



public ArrayList<String> accountList()  { return m_acctList; }
public ApiController controller()       { return m_controller; }
public JFrame frame()           { return connect.frame; }

}
```

next class

```
 public class Connection implements IConnectionHandler{

static int port = 4001;
Quotes quotes;

JFrame frame;
CPanel panel;

boolean connected = false;

JTextArea logIn = new JTextArea();
JTextArea logOut = new JTextArea();
JTextArea msgBox = new JTextArea();

Logger loggerIn = new Logger(logIn);
Logger loggerOut = new Logger(logOut);

ApiController m_controller = new ApiController(this, loggerIn, loggerOut);

final ArrayList<String> m_acctList = new ArrayList<String>();

Connection(){
    frame = new JFrame("Trader");
    panel = new CPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setSize(800,400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

class CPanel extends JComponent{

    Point frameLoc = frame.getLocation();
    Dimension frameSize = frame.getSize();

    JLabel text = new JLabel("Messages");

    JScrollPane messages = new JScrollPane(msgBox);


    CPanel(){

        setLayout(null);

        add(text);
        text.setBounds(frameLoc.x+5, frameLoc.y+5, 
                text.getPreferredSize().width, text.getPreferredSize().height);

        add(messages);
        msgBox.setEditable(false);
        msgBox.setLineWrap(true);

        messages.setBounds(text.getLocation().x, text.getLocation().y+text.getSize().height+10, 
                720, 300);


        m_controller.connect(null, port, 0);

    }


}


 @Override public void connected() {
    show( "connected");

    m_controller.reqCurrentTime( new ApiController.ITimeHandler() {
        @Override public void currentTime(long time) {
            show( "Server date/time is " + Formats.fmtDate(time * 1000) );
        }
    });

    m_controller.reqBulletins( true, new ApiController.IBulletinHandler() {
        @Override public void bulletin(int msgId, Types.NewsType newsType, String message, String exchange) {
            String str = String.format( "Received bulletin:  type=%s  exchange=%s", newsType, exchange);
            show( str);
            show( message);
        }
    });    

      //  Quotes quotes = new Quotes();
}

@Override public void disconnected() {
    show( "disconnected");
}

@Override public void accountList(ArrayList<String> list) {
    show( "Received account list");
    m_acctList.clear();
    m_acctList.addAll( list);
}

@Override public void error(Exception e) {
    show( e.toString() );
}

@Override public void message(int id, int errorCode, String errorMsg) {
    show( id + " " + errorCode + " " + errorMsg);
}

@Override public void show( final String str) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            msgBox.append(str);
            msgBox.append( "\n\n");

            Dimension d = msgBox.getSize();
            msgBox.scrollRectToVisible( new Rectangle( 0, d.height, 1, 1) );
        }
    });
}



private static class Logger implements ILogger{
    final private JTextArea msgBox;

    Logger(JTextArea area){
        msgBox = area;
    }

    @Override public void log(final String str) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
//                  m_area.append(str);
//                  
//                  Dimension d = m_area.getSize();
//                  m_area.scrollRectToVisible( new Rectangle( 0, d.height, 1, 1) );
            }
        });
    }

    }
 }
```

and lastly

```
public class Quotes {

int numberOfStocks = 0;
JTextArea msgBox = Trader.INSTANCE.connect.msgBox;
String symbol;

File file = new File("/Users/spencerclayman/Desktop/IB_API/API_Data/stockList.txt");

ArrayList<quote> stockList = new ArrayList();
Quotes(){

    msgBox.append("Getting stock quotes");
    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(file);){

       while(input.hasNextLine()){
            symbol = input.nextLine();
            newStock(newContract(symbol));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){msgBox.append("Error getting quotes");}

    try{wait(10000);}catch(Exception ex){msgBox.append("error waiting - quote");}

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStocks() -1 ; i++){

        msgBox.append(stockList.get(i).m_description
        + " - " + stockList.get(i).m_last +"\n");
    }
}




void newStock( NewContract contract) {
    quote stock = new quote(contract.description());
    stockList.add(stock);
    Trader.INSTANCE.controller().reqTopMktData(contract, "", false, stock);
}

void newStock( quote stock) {
    stockList.add(stock);
}

public void desubscribe() {
    for (quote stock : stockList) {
        Trader.INSTANCE.controller().cancelTopMktData(stock);
    }
}




public int numberOfStocks(){

    try(Scanner input = new Scanner(file);){

        while(input.hasNextLine()){
            numberOfStocks++;
            input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){msgBox.append("Error getting symbols");}

    return numberOfStocks;
}



static class quote extends TopMktDataAdapter{

            String m_description;
    double m_bid;
    double m_ask;
    double m_last;
    long m_lastTime;
    int m_bidSize;
    int m_askSize;
    double m_close;
    int m_volume;
    boolean m_frozen;

            quote(String description){ 
                m_description = description;

            }



            public String change() {
        return m_close == 0 ? null : fmtPct( (m_last - m_close) / m_close);
    }

        @Override public void tickPrice( NewTickType tickType, double price, int canAutoExecute) {
    switch( tickType) {
            case BID:
                m_bid = price;
                break;
            case ASK:
                m_ask = price;
                break;
            case LAST:
                m_last = price;
                break;
            case CLOSE:
                m_close = price;
                break;
        }
    }

        @Override public void tickSize( NewTickType tickType, int size) {
        switch( tickType) {
            case BID_SIZE:
                m_bidSize = size;
                break;
            case ASK_SIZE:
                m_askSize = size;
                break;
            case VOLUME:
                m_volume = size;
                break;
        }
    }

        @Override public void tickString(NewTickType tickType, String value) {
        switch( tickType) {
            case LAST_TIMESTAMP:
                m_lastTime = Long.parseLong( value) * 1000;
                break;
        }
    }

        @Override public void marketDataType(Types.MktDataType marketDataType) {
        m_frozen = marketDataType == Types.MktDataType.Frozen;
    } 

}




    public NewContract newContract(String symbol){
        NewContract c = new NewContract();

        c.symbol(symbol);
        c.secType(Types.SecType.STK);
        c.exchange("SMART");
        c.currency("USD");

        return c;
    }


 }
```

again i am highly doubtful that code has anything to do with it. Im assumign its a problem with the IDE.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, you should never modify any UI component from outside the Event Dispatching Thread and you should never do anything that would otherwise block the EDT (like, `Thread.sleep`, or long running loops or blocking IO or ...).  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details